# How to disable chromedriver auto updates

Tags: windows, selenium, google-chrome, selenium-chromedriver, coded-ui-tests

One of the recurring questions I have found is "How to disable google chrome updates"

After some research, renaming the update folder and making sure the service gupdate never runs does the trick.

The issue I am now facing is chromedriver auto-updating, after running the first test.
[relevant vstestlog](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XhVvE.png)

Can't really find much information on this, so:
Is there a way to prevent this update from happening automatically ?

additional info:

The setup we use are disposable VMs that spawn and get destroyed at the end of the automated test run, these are supported by packer images.
chrome and chromedriver are installed via chocolatey, with the version pinned.

We basically want to ensure automated test pipelines keep running until we address the Google chrome and chromedriver updates (create a new image)
I'd also take suggestions regarding a better way of handling the version updates (automated can cause some false-negatives as the coded UI tests may not be prepared to run in it yet)

Answer (score 1):

Webdriver manager is the solution for these drivers you don't need to download and set up path for particular browsers. webdriver is a function that is doing

[WebDriverManager](https://www.npmjs.com/package/webdriver-manager)

Comment: Thank you for the answer, although this would work around the problem, it does not really address the underlying issue making it a workaround.
chromedriver won't be launched via webdrivermanager, and so the auto-update issue persists, these are coded UI test runs with vstest.

Ideally, I would like to understand why this is the behavior of chromedriver (self-update) between test executions and if it can be corrected without changing the whole approach to coded UI tests

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can download manually webdriver from https://chromedriver.chromium.org/downloads, then extract to another directory. Or, if you have seen this path on console, you can copy the absolute path

[console image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1Ewbl.png)

Then, you can pass parameter 1 in inisialization by absolute path to the executable driver that've been copied.

```
driver = webdriver.Chrome( "path/to/chromedriver")
```